# MainWindow is nil on Mac OS Big Sur 11.0

Tags: swift, macos, macos-big-sur

On the previous version of mac os, everything was alright loading window with the code below worked properly. But with the first official release, Big Sur MainWindow is always nil

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    self.applicationCoordinator.setupApplicationLanguage(language: .en)
    
    windowViewController = MainWindowController()
    windowViewController?.windowDelegate = self
    windowViewController?.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    windowViewController?.showWindow(self)

    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.title = ""
    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.styleMask.remove(NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable)
    
    self.applicationCoordinator.setupApplicationWindowMinSize()
    self.applicationCoordinator.loadInitialCoordinator(with: self.applicationCoordinator)
  }
```

NSApplication.shared.windows contain MainWindowController window inside, but NSApplication.shared.mainWindow would be nil.

***SOLUTION FOR THIS BUG:***
Previously NSApplication.shared.mainWindow can be updated before the application becomes active. But from Big Sur, it was fixed and NSApplication.shared.mainWindow would be set the first window in their window stack when the application becomes active

Comment: Where is this code located? Show your MainWindowController declaration

Comment: @LeoDabus already updated the code in question. Is it important what inside MainWindowController? NSApplication.shared.windows would contain MainWindowController window. But NSApplication.shared.mainWindow is nil

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not using XIB or Storyboard. Everything was created by code

Comment: Put your code in applicationDidBecomeActive instead of applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: @mmm bad idea. Every time as your app would-be active you will do something code? ( My solution is perfect )

Comment: My answer is the reply to a bug report I got from apple. That is where they say the code has to go. Of course, if the variable is already defined (on subsequent app becoming active) there is no need to redo the assignment. I don't particularly like it, but Apple tells me that's how it should be done.